# Why can't I catch the exception in this code?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I'm trying to detect foreign languages in a dataframe using 'langdetect' library for Python.

```
for e in food['product_name'].dropna():
    if detect(e) == 'zh':
        print e
```

Here im trying to print every chinese word found in a specific column.

However, at some point I get this error message:

```
LangDetectException: No features in text.
```

I understand this happens when a number, a blank space or a string that is not a word (reference code, mail address...) is found.

All I want is to catch an exception and handle the situation accordingly BUT i don't know how to do it. Here's my attempt:

```
for e in food['product_name'].dropna():
    if detect(e) == 'zh':
        try:
            print e
        except LangDetectException:
            pass
```

Can someone please help me fix this poorly written snippet ? Obviously there's something wrong with it but I don't know what exactly !

Comment: The exception is happening in the `detect` call, not the `print`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What am i supposed to change then ?

Comment: `raise` the exception? I'm not clear on what you're asking.

Comment: Write a guard-clause: like _if this is an unwanted result - raise an exception_

Comment: It looks like you're trying to _catch_ an exception, not raise one. So you need to put the code that's actually raising the exception inside the `try` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above the exception is being raised by detect, so you need to wrap that call in your `try` block:

```
for e in food['product_name'].dropna():
    try:
        if detect(e) == 'zh':
            print e
    except LangDetectException:
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. finally I understand why it didn't work ! Unfortunately, i now have an error showing: 'name 'LangDetectException' is not defined'. Am i supposed to define the exception ?

Comment: You need to import the custom exception using `from langdetect.lang_detect_exception import LangDetectException`

Comment: Than you so much @wpercy and Luke Smith

Comment: @solub BTW, it's generally a Good Idea to actually do something when you catch an exception, rather than ignoring it with `pass`. Of course, that depends on your actual use case. But you could, eg keep a count of how many items raise the exception, or save those items somewhere.